Next js and Prisma Image upload
When i upload images, it creates that folder, but doesnt upload any image to that folder!
Here is uploading Component:
"use client"
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { FaStar, FaRegStar } from "react-icons/fa";
import { FaCirclePlus } from "react-icons/fa6";
import { IoIosCloseCircle } from "react-icons/io";
import {useAppDispatch, useAppSelector} from "@/redux/store";
import {setReviewPopUp} from "@/redux/reducers/reviewReducer";

const ReviewPopUp = ({ locationId }: { locationId: number }) => {
  const reviewtate =  useAppSelector(state => state.review);
  const [rating, setRating] = useState(0);
  const [description, setDescription] = useState("");
  const [images, setImages] = useState<File[]>([]);
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  if(!reviewtate.reviewPopup){
    return null;
  }
    const handleStarClick = (value: number) => {
    setRating(value);
  };
  const handleImageUpload = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const uploadedFiles = e.target.files;
    if (uploadedFiles) {
      setImages(Array.from(uploadedFiles));
    }
  };

  const removeImage = (fileToRemove: File) => {
    setImages((prevFiles) => prevFiles.filter((file) => file !== fileToRemove));
  };

  const handleReviewAdd = async () => {
    try {
      const formData = new FormData();
      images.forEach((image) => {
        formData.append("images", image);
      });
      const response = await axios.post("/api/reviews/add", formData, {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        },
      });
      console.log(response.data);
      // Handle success, display success message, etc.
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error uploading images:", error);
      // Handle error, display error message, etc.
    }
  };

  return (
      <div className="z-50 fixed left-0 top-0 flex h-full w-full items-center justify-center bg-black bg-opacity-65">
        <div className="flex h-full w-full max-w-[35rem] flex-col space-y-10 overflow-y-scroll bg-white p-5 md:h-2/3 md:rounded-xl">
          <div className="flex items-center justify-between">
            <h1 className="mb-2 text-2xl font-bold tracking-wider">
              Ievieto atsuksmi
            </h1>
            <IoIosCloseCircle
                className="text-3xl hover:text-close"
                onClick={()=>{dispatch(setReviewPopUp(false))}}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="flex flex-col justify-center space-y-3">
            <h1 className="tracking-wide">Vērtējums ({rating}/5)</h1>
            <div className="mb-10 flex w-full justify-center">
              <div className="flex space-x-6">
                {[...Array(5)].map((_, index) =>
                    index < rating ? (
                        <FaStar
                            key={index}
                            className="text-4xl text-primary"
                            onClick={() => handleStarClick(index + 1)}
                        />
                    ) : (
                        <FaRegStar
                            key={index}
                            className="text-4xl text-primary opacity-35"
                            onClick={() => handleStarClick(index + 1)}
                        />
                    ),
                )}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="flex flex-col justify-center space-y-3">
            <h1 className=" tracking-wide">Apraksts</h1>
            <div className="flex w-full flex-col">
              <div className="space-x-05 flex w-full items-center">
                <div className="flex w-full flex-col justify-center">
                <textarea
                    placeholder="Apraksts"
                    onChange={(e) => {
                      setDescription(e.target.value);
                    }}
                    className="min-h-36 w-full rounded-xl border border-secondary bg-secondary-lightest p-2 text-sm hover:border-primary focus:outline-none"
                    // onChange={(e) => {
                    //   dispatch(setPassword(e.target.value));
                    // }}
                ></textarea>
                  {/*{registerState.errors.password.error !== "" ? (*/}
                  {/*    <p className="text-xs text-red-600">*/}
                  {/*      {" "}*/}
                  {/*      {registerState.errors.password.error}{" "}*/}
                  {/*    </p>*/}
                  {/*) : (*/}
                  {/*    ""*/}
                  {/*)}*/}
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="flex flex-col justify-center space-y-3">
            <h1 className=" tracking-wide">Attēli</h1>
            <div className="grid w-full grid-cols-3 gap-2">
              {images.map((image, index) => (
                  <div
                      key={index}
                      className="relative flex h-24 items-center justify-center rounded-xl"
                  >
                    <img
                        src={URL.createObjectURL(image)}
                        className="h-full w-full rounded-xl object-cover"
                        alt={`Image ${index}`}
                    />
                    <IoIosCloseCircle
                        className="absolute right-0 top-0 m-1 text-xl text-primary"
                        onClick={() => {removeImage(image)}}
                    />
                  </div>
              ))}
              <div className="flex min-h-24 items-center justify-center rounded-xl border-2 border-dashed border-primary">
                <input
                    type="file"
                    id="img"
                    multiple
                    accept="image/*"
                    className="hidden"
                    onChange={handleImageUpload}
                />
                <label htmlFor="img">
                  <FaCirclePlus className="text-3xl text-primary cursor-pointer" />
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <button
              className="main-btn mb-2 w-full py-2 text-2xl text-white"
              type="button"
              onClick={handleReviewAdd}
          >
            Ievietot
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
  );
};

export default ReviewPopUp;

Here is api route:
import { NextResponse, NextRequest } from "next/server";
import multer from "multer";

const upload = multer({ dest: "public/assets/images/" });
interface MulterRequest extends NextRequest {
    file: File;
}

export const config = {
    api: {
        bodyParser: false,
    },
};

export async function POST(request: MulterRequest) {
    try {
        await new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
            //@ts-ignore
            upload.array("images")(request as any, null, (err: any) => {
                if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
                    console.error("File upload error:", err.message);
                    reject({ status: 400, error: "File upload error" });
                } else if (err) {
                    console.error("Server error:", err.message);
                    reject({ status: 500, error: "Internal server error" });
                } else {
                    resolve();
                }
            });
        });

        const formData = request.body;
        const file = request.file;

        return NextResponse.json({ message: "Data received successfully" }, { status: 201 });
    } catch (error:any) {
        console.error("Error processing form data:", error);
        const status = error.status || 500;
        const errorMessage = error.error || "Internal server error";
        return NextResponse.json({ error: errorMessage }, { status });
    }
}


And when uploading, response from api is "Data received successfully", but there is not images!
My main goal is to be able upload multiple images, and there should be functionality for client before uploading, that he can remove some images!
